# Using Spring and Hibernate/JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

Hi i'm trying use spring in my project that uses hibernate. i'm facing a problem making it work and i have no idea what is causing it.
I tried to make a new project with spring and it works fine. so i'm guessing that hibernate and spring are having conflicts.

i've been searching for hours and all of them says that the web.xml is not inside the WEB-INF folder. but my web.xml is inside the WEB-INF along with the spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml and the jsp.

web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Test</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.controller" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Error:

```
07:59:43,043 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.3.Final-redhat-1
07:59:43,293 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.1.5.Final-redhat-1
07:59:43,362 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015899: JBoss EAP 6.3.0.GA (AS 7.4.0.Final-redhat-19) starting
07:59:44,521 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) JBAS015005: Reliable deployment behaviour is not possible when auto-deployment of exploded content is enabled (i.e. deployment without use of ".dodeploy"' marker files). Configuration of auto-deployment of exploded content is not recommended in any situation where reliability is desired. Configuring the deployment scanner's auto-deploy-exploded setting to "false" is recommended.
07:59:44,555 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-6) XNIO Version 3.0.10.GA-redhat-1
07:59:44,563 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-6) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.10.GA-redhat-1
07:59:44,564 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
07:59:44,581 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBoss Remoting version (unknown)
07:59:44,657 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
07:59:44,724 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
07:59:44,735 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 42) JBAS013171: Activating Security Subsystem
07:59:44,740 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 35) JBAS012605: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main, 1.2]
07:59:44,746 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS010153: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
07:59:44,749 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
07:59:44,774 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.logging] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.0.26.Final-redhat-1)
07:59:44,795 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS013170: Current PicketBox version=4.0.19.SP8-redhat-1
07:59:44,808 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
07:59:44,809 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
07:59:44,815 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
07:59:45,406 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWEB003001: Coyote HTTP/1.1 initializing on : http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
07:59:45,450 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWEB003000: Coyote HTTP/1.1 starting on: http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
07:59:45,490 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /home/patrick/jbdevstudio/runtimes/jboss-eap/standalone/deployments
07:59:45,501 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:4447
07:59:45,502 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:9999
07:59:45,516 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "Copy of BEO.war" (runtime-name: "Copy of BEO.war")
07:59:45,798 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
07:59:45,805 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.3.0.Final-redhat-3
07:59:46,865 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for BEO
07:59:47,154 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
07:59:47,155 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
07:59:47,250 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version 9.4)
07:59:47,296 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) JBAS011402: Starting Persistence Unit Service 'Copy of BEO.war#BEO'
07:59:47,459 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final-redhat-2}
07:59:47,470 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.14.SP1-redhat-1}
07:59:47,472 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
07:59:47,475 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
07:59:47,500 INFO  [org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: BEO
    ...]
07:59:47,616 WARN  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
07:59:47,617 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
07:59:47,617 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) HHH000006: Autocommit mode: true
07:59:47,618 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) HHH000401: using driver [org.postgresql.Driver] at URL [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/BEO]
07:59:47,619 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=patrick, password=****, autocommit=true, release_mode=auto}
07:59:47,941 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
07:59:47,952 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07:59:48,024 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory
07:59:48,028 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
07:59:48,069 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 4.3.1.Final-redhat-1
07:59:48,656 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
07:59:48,656 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
07:59:48,658 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) HHH000396: Updating schema
07:59:48,690 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) HHH000261: Table found: public.accounts
07:59:48,691 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) HHH000037: Columns: [password, firstname, user_id, username, lastname]
07:59:48,691 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
07:59:48,691 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) HHH000126: Indexes: [accounts_pkey, accounts_username_key]
07:59:48,692 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) HHH000232: Schema update complete
07:59:48,761 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) JBAS018210: Register web context: /Copy of BEO
07:59:48,778 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/Copy of BEO]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
07:59:48,779 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/Copy of BEO]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
07:59:48,890 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS018559: Deployed "Copy of BEO.war" (runtime-name : "Copy of BEO.war")
07:59:48,978 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
07:59:48,979 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
07:59:48,979 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss EAP 6.3.0.GA (AS 7.4.0.Final-redhat-19) started in 6269ms - Started 263 of 301 services (59 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

Comment: Can you describe the problem better? It's not clear what it is and therefore difficult to help fix "it".

Comment: saw this error,

No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath.

they said that this problem occurs if the web.xml is not inside the WEB-INF folder. but the web.xml of my project is inside the WEB-INF

Comment: That just looks like typical logs with a few warnings. Have you enabled DEBUG logs like it suggests?

Comment: do you have only single spring configuration-no ROOT context?. Why i am asking you only scanning the `controller` package. I suspect your service and database layer are configured with spring?

Comment: There is no error so please explain what isn't working that you expected that should be working.

Answer (score -1):

> you can use following configuration for your project

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>NxtLife Demo</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<!-- Spring Security Filter needed to security configuration to check and 
    apply security to all application urls -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml
        /WEB-INF/security-config.xml 
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

> spring-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beansxmlns:xsi="htt//www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
```

xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.nxtlife" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/img/**" location="/img/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<tx:annotation-driven />
<!-- Default bean name is 'mongo' -->
<mongo:mongo host="localhost" port="27017" />

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongo" />
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="kaya_db" />

</bean>

<!-- To translate any MongoExceptions thrown in @Repository annotated classes -->
<context:annotation-config />


<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer"
    id="tilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/**/views.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver"
    id="viewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kaya_db" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="nxtlife" />
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.nxtlife.model" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">

        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
    p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory">
</bean>
```

> pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>NxtLife_Demo</groupId>
<artifactId>NxtLife_Demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <!-- jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- servlet-api -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Data Mongo Driver -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Apache Tiles -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Jackson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.31</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--  jersy web services -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.22</version>
    </dependency>



</dependencies>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

> you can use code according to your requirment.